# Error "Unable to launch iisexpress web server" While running asp.net mvc Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJXa.png)I was trying to run my project but getting error "Unable to launch iis express Web server" . i have tried deleting applicationhost.config file and also tried deleting  .vs folder still getting same error. Every morning i get this problem when i open project first time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the automatically-created IISExpress folder, which is usually located at %userprofile%/Documents, e.g. C:\Users[you]\Documents\IISExpress.

Don't worry, VS should create it again - correctly, this time - once you run your solution again.

EDIT: Command line for deleting the folder:

```
rmdir /s /q "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress"
```